# Export VBA Editor (VBE) settings

Tags: excel, export, settings, customization, vbe

I've made a lot of changes to the VBA editor on my PC, including customization of toolbars. Is there a way to export these so that I can use them on a different system, without having to start from the scratch?

Answer (score 8):

See here:

[How to restore VBA Editor to its initial settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810053/how-to-restore-vba-editor-to-its-initial-settings)

Different question, but has the answer to your question too.

Basically you need to back up the key from registry under: `HKEY_CURRENTUSER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\6.0\Common`

**Edit:**

Depending on your Office version, you might need to use a bit different key. For me it was:
`HKEY_CURRENTUSER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common`

But it works. Now if the source and the target machines have different Office versions, that might be interesting. Worth a try though.

Comment: Can these setting be saved/exported via VBA?