# How do I reset my Visual Basic Editor Layout?

Tags: display, vbe

Something has gone terribly wrong with my VBE layout. I originally closed my Project explorer and was trying to figure out how to restore it when I made some changes under the window tab of the ribbon.

I've restored the Project explorer but I can't for the life of me reset my code window to display only the current module I'm working on. The resulting layout is hideous, truly atrocious, and difficult to work with.

[disgusting VBE display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpvWC.png)

I've already tried resetting my registry key for VBA as [recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810053/how-to-restore-vba-editor-to-its-initial-settings) to no avail. I believe I clicked on either Cascade or Tile Vertically to make the code block appear this way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tagged both VBA and VBE?

Comment: It's not a setting, it's just that all the code windows you had open have been minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've never hit 'Restore Down' before on the Windows controls? Click it again (it will now be called Maximise) to put things right.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the code windows in your layout to how you like them.  Then add a module to your project, then exit Access.  It seems to save the layout at that point.
You can then delete the empty module.

Comment: Funnily enough, this doesn't answer the OP's question, but trying to search for a solution to my problem, where the VBE layout in Access kept forgetting my changes, lead me to this page, and your post resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Click the square box of any of the windows in the upper right corner for it to fill the window, and then you can navigate using the project folder structure to the left, or the Window menu at top.  Windows can be dragged and "docked" at different positions. For step by step instructions on how to dock windows in the VBE, including video [see this site](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/VBEDocking.asp?AllComments=True), for example