# How can I correct VBA editor settings

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

After I changed the "System Locale" of my Windows-10 PC from USA to Turkey and later get it back, my Excel VBA editor started to behave weird.  The reason might be different though.

Some parts of my code seems blank, as if highligted black.  When I type new characters, first I can see them, later when I go to next line, the characters become blanked too.  Please see the picture attached.

[image]

Comment: Check under Tools -> Options -> Editor Format what your Code Colors look like. They may have changed. Remove (Auto) and use an explicit Color to try if that is the Problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810053/how-to-restore-vba-editor-to-its-initial-settings

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. It doesn't work unfortunatelly.